# When an SQL query fails to return anything, how can I tell the shell to return a "false" instead?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, programming, sql

This may not have anything to do with SQL in particular, because I am sure other commands will do this as well.

In this case, I send a query through the shell, and if the query does not match any table, literally nothing will be returned, not even a Carriage Return.

How can I script my shell that in such a case, a `0` or `false` is returned instead?

Here is my sample command which is producing my issue:

```
mysql -u Popey --password='Misses Jono' -s -N --disable-column-names -e 
"select term_id from shuttleworth.wp_terms where name = 'nonExistentName' LIMIT 1;"
```

Comment: How will you tell the difference between an empty result set and one that contains one item of one column with the value `false` or `0`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster In this case; the cell values are all id integers. Good question though, with the answer basically being "hope"

Answer (score 0):

`-v` option for verbose mode should give you more output. I can't try this right now, since I don't have a SQL server running.

Answer (score 0):

My cousin offered me this solution. Tested it, and it works.

Single Line:

```
response=$(mysql -u popey --password='Misses Jono' -s -N --disable-column-names -e "select term_id from shuttleworth.wp_terms where name = 'non-existent-name' LIMIT 1;") && if [ -z "$response" ]; then echo false; else echo $response; fi`
```

---

Broken Down:

```
response=
    $(mysql 
      -u popey 
      --password='Misses Jono' 
      -s -N --disable-column-names 
      -e 
          "SELECT term_id 
           FROM shuttleworth.wp_terms
           WHERE name = 'non-existent-name' 
           LIMIT 1;"
      ) 
&& if [ -z "$response" ]; 
   then echo false; 
   else echo $response; 
   fi
```